# main conjecture of Iwasawa theory implies Herbrand-Ribet

Tags: nt.number-theory, iwasawa-theory, reference-request

I need a reference/proof for "main conjecture of Iwasawa theory => refinement of Herbrand-Ribet ($v_p(B_{p-i}) = v_p(|A_i|)$, where $A_i$ denotes the $i$-th eigenspace of the Galois group acting on the ideal class group mod $p$)".

Comment: Isn't that in the second edition of Washington, cyclotomic fields?



Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement and proof are given in Mazur–Wiles starting at page 216.

Comment: It can also be found in http://www.math.clemson.edu/~jimlb/CourseNotes/iwasawa.pdf p. 65ff.

Comment: New link to Brown's notes mentioned in the other comment: http://www.math.caltech.edu/~jimlb/iwasawa.pdf